# Insert text into clipboard in android using java

Tags: java, android, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I am trying to use the clipboard in android as described here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_clipboard.htm

```
ClipboardManager myClipboard;
            myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("code", eventCode);
            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

However, `getSystemService` requires 2 arguments instead of just 1, but I can't find anything about it.

Thanks to Usama Altaf's comment, I was able to solve this issue.
This is my now working code:

```
ClipboardManager myClipboard;
            ClipboardManager clipboard = context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ClipboardManager.class);

            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("code", eventCode);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Comment: "However, getSystemService requires 2 arguments instead of just 1" -- where does this code reside? The tutorial that you are reading appears to assume that the code resides in an activity or other `Context` subclass, and there, `getSystemService()` takes a single parameter.

Comment: `ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);`

Comment: @CommonsWare This code resides in an adapter class.

Comment: You will need to call `getSystemService()` on your `Activity`, pass the `ClipboardManager` into the adapter, or move your "copy stuff to the clipboard" logic out of the adapter.